# How to link with libtiff

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, makefile

How do I specify in my makefile that I want to link with the `libtiff` library. Just specifying -ltiff in LDFLAGS is not working.

Comment: Did you also tell the linker about the library path? `-L...`

Comment: You can use `ldd` command to check that you binary was linked with libtiff.

Comment: what error message do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can use the -L flag (see either manual for the compiler - I am assuming that you are using gcc or g++

or

Set the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the path for the library

But you should also consider static or dynamic linking. The documentation for both compilers are very good to explain how to do either.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the following options for compilation.

g++ -L[path of libtiff on your machine] -ltiff [your remaining options] ...

-L option is used to tell gcc, where to find the librarires you are trying to link with.